# Add video sequence as background for 2d animation

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, motion-capture, 2d

Hey so I'm messing around with the 2d animation aspect of blender 2.82 and I can't figure out how to set the background as a video sequence like how you would do if you were motion tracking and rotoscoping.. I don't know if I'm missing something here. But I'm just trying to add a video sequence as reference without having to load each individual frame as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add an empty.
- In *Object Data Properties* make it display as *Image*
- Choose video & set image *Source* to *Movie*

Comment: lol that worked i dont know why i had such a brain fart

Comment: Can you go into more detail on how to do this?

Comment: @DavidGiven is possible you see the movie as a line, you need to rotate it. Also it will take the project frames as the total frames. There's a refresh button next to the Frames value to match movie length (all this inside Object Data Properties).